# Tensorflow - Conditionally writing summary to tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using Tensorboard to visualize Tensorflow runs, and I would like to have a summary graph that only writes a value once per epoch.

I want to do something like this:

```
with graph.as_default():
    tf_ending = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
    tf.scalar_summary('Loss', loss) # Some summaries are written every time
    if tf_ending:
        # This summary should only get written sometimes.
        tf.scalar_summary('Total for Epoch', epoch_total)
```

I have the feeling that I need to do something other than `tf.merge_all_summaries()` and manage the sets of summaries separately, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add a custom Summary protobuf to the SummaryWriter. At the end of each epoch (outside of session/graph), you can add something like:

```
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag='Total for Epoch',simple_value=epoch_total)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, train_step)
```

This, however, requires the value (epoch_total) to be returned via the tensorflow graph (sess.run). Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do something like this, however you do see this used in TF examples, e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_eval.py) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py).